# jQuery load event - discrepancies in usage

Tags: javascript, jquery

A lot of the time we load an image via jQuery in the background before appending it to the DOM like so

```
var image = $('<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" />');
image.load(function(){
  //the image is now loaded and can be appended
});
```

Although stated [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) that there are caveats to this method (that ultimately it is not 100% reliable), it is a good method for what we need.

Taking this principle, I want to load an iframe and wait for it to be loaded before proceeding

```
//method does not fire
var iframe = $('<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>');
iframe.load(function(){
  //the iframe is now loaded and can be appended
});
```

However, it appears to be so that the iframe needs to be in the DOM before that load event is called, in contrast to the loading of the image:

```
//method now fires
var iframe = $('<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>');
$("body").append(iframe);
iframe.load(function(){
  //the iframe is now loaded and can be appended
});
```

What is the reason for this? I cannot seem to find it documented anywhere. I know in practice it'd be easy enough to set the style to display none then manipulate it once it's loaded, but I'm more interested in the why as opposed to the how. Thanks!

Comment: the _why_ is actually really complicated; in short: the iframe runs xml and js, so it needs an owner document, whereas images are dumb and not subject to the SOP to merely load/display (attach)